# How to specify a Default value to Not Serialize

Tags: protobuf-net

Assuming the following class, is there any way to provide a "If the member has a particular value, don't serialise it"

```
Imports ProtoBuf
<ProtoContract()>
Public Class DateTransferTest
    <ProtoMember(1)>
    Public Property TransferDate As DateTime
End Class
```

For example in protobuf, if an integer has a value of 0 it isn't serialised.

eg.

```
<ProtoMember(1), ProtoNoSerialiseValue(New DateTime(1980, 12, 15))
```

I know this would probably add overhead but wondering if maybe there is some way or other to do it. In my project Wiresize is more important than a little performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1. You can add a `[DefaultValue(...)]` (or the equivalent syntax in VB), noting that date-times need to be stored (in attributes) as strings, and that the library use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the formatter, so `[DefaultValue("12/15/1980")]` should do the job
2. You can use a few conditional-serialization patterns; the easiest is the `ShouldSerialize*` pattern, shown here in C# for my convenience:

   ```
   private static readonly defaultDate = new DateTime(1980, 12, 15);
   public bool ShouldSerializeTransferDate() {
       return DateTransferTest != defaultDate;
   }
   ```

(for `XmlSerializer` the `ShouldSerialize*` method needs to be `public`; protobuf-net will use a `private` method if you prefer, though)

Note that in either case, you should ensure that the date defaults correctly, for example setting the value to the default via a field-initializer, constructor, or before-deserialization callback.

Comment: function should be ShouldSerializeTransferDate (propertyname)
very very cool, thanks

Comment: @PaulFarry copy/paste error; fixed. That mechanism is shamelessly borrowed from `TypeDescriptor` and `XmlSerializer` which support the same approach